# connect multiple different terminals to the same slime instance

Tags: emacs, slime

I am still a novice when it comes to working with emacs and slime.

I was wondering if there is a way to start a lisp (say SBCL) on a local port and then connect multiple different slime sessions to it?

For example, if I am using tmux/screen and want to have different emacs sessions between each window, would I be able to connect all the slime instances to the same lisp so that all the emacs sessions were sharing a repl allowing me to compile in any of the emacs sessions and the one running repl will have those changes?

Answer (score 2):

I am using LispWorks 6.1 32 bit Professional Edition. I prefer to use (Spac)emacs for my editing in multiple tmux sessions, one session for each project that I work on.

These are the steps I follow:

1. Start LispWorks Listener REPL.
2. Load swank without going through the emacs route:

   ```
   (load "/path/to/swank-loader.lisp")
   (swank-loader:init)
   (setf swank:*use-dedicated-output-stream* nil)
   (swank:create-server :port 4005  :dont-close t)
   ```
3. Then in my iTerm tab with tmux session for some project 1, I do M-x slime- 
   connect and connect to host and port as in step 2.
4. Repeat step 3 for another tmux session with another lisp project code.

With this setup I can load code from multiple projects I am working on in the same lisp image. So far I have not found any major problems while doing so.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the lisp system you're using, on the features it supports, i.e. whether your SBCL has multi-threading enabled (cf. `(member :sb-thread *features*)` and on the setting of `SWANK:*COMMUNICATION-STYLE*`, cf. the [Slime docs](http://common-lisp.net/project/slime/doc/html/Communication-style.html#Communication-style).

Comment: I have SBCL 1.2 on a debian system. SB-THREAD is enabled. The `*COMMUNICATION-STYLE*` is `:SPAWN`

It isn't clear to me which style I should be using to connect multiple slime sessions to the same lisp process nor how to do it.